# Creating a collection with a function to obtain the next member

Tags: c#

I need to accumulate values into a collection, based on an arbitrary function. Each value is derived from calling a function on the previous value.

My current attempt:

```
public static T[] Aggregate<T>(this T source, Func<T, T> func)
{
  var arr = new List<T> { };
  var current = source;
  while(current != null)
  {
    arr.Add(current);
    current = func(current);
  };
  return arr.ToArray();
}
```

Is there a built-in .Net Framework function to do this?

Comment: So what did you attempt to do in your attempts to create such a function?  What problems did you have with your attempted solution?

Comment: @Servy He wants to know whether such a function already exists, not how to implement it.

Comment: Did you look at 'Stack' and 'Queue' collection types?

Comment: @TomasZubiri The question asks for an implementation of a set of requirements that might or might not be in the framework.  But anyway, asking for an external source is off topic on SO, if that's the only solution that qualifies for the OP.

Comment: @Servy, I'm not asking for an implementation. I'm asking for a pointer to an existing function or null (no such function).

Comment: @toddmo Then that's just off topic.

Comment: I suggest you provide an example that compiles. Tell us what currentLocation is and how you created it, and where the rest of the variables comes from. Also, you cannot have a collection of variables, collections hold values.

Comment: @TomasZubiri Well, an array is actually a collection of *variables*, not a collection of values, but it's the only exception in C#.  Any other collection will be a collection of values.

Comment: @toddmo https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Servy, why would my question plus an answer like "I think what you want is the `Aggregate` function" be off topic. That's a perfect matching Q and A.

Comment: @toddmo Because asking for a link to an external resource isn't on topic; they don't result in good questions, or useful answers.

Comment: So since you already have an implementation, what is your problem with it?  In what way is it failing to meet your requirements?

Comment: @Servy, I made that to keep you from closing it. I don't want to re-invent the wheel. Why would I merrily skip on down the road with my hand rolled function if there is one already in the framework that I'm simply not aware of? For example, I would have never thought to search for `Unfold`.

Comment: This operation is usually called `Unfold` and doesn't exist in the BCL. The F# core library does implement it in the `Seq` module however.

Comment: Perhaps your "contrived example" would be a bit less contrived and a bit more explanatory if you gave the input as well as the output... Because there is already an [Aggregate<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) function in LINQ, but can't be sure if it meets your requirements because I don't know the input.

Comment: @toddmo Why would you spend considerable amounts of time trying to find someone else's implementation of something that you've already implemented and that already works?  Anyway, as I said, asking for a link to some external reference isn't on topic, so the fact that you already have a working implementation doesn't make the question any more on topic.

Comment: @Servy, If that "Someone" is Microsoft, then it's simply best practice to use the correct .Net Framework function if it exists. That goes without saying. And in some arcane cases like advanced set manipulation, searching is hard because the search terms are not known or intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operation is usually called `Unfold`. There's no built-in version but it is implemented in `FSharp.Core`, so you could wrap that:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Unfold<T, TState>(TState init, Func<TState, T> gen)
{
    var liftF = new Converter<TState, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption<Tuple<T, TState>>>(x =>
    {
        var r = gen(x);
        if (r == null)
        {
            return Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption<Tuple<T, TState>>.None;
        }
        else
        {
            return Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption<Tuple<T, TState>>.Some(Tuple.Create(r, x));
        }
    });

    var ff = Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<TState, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption<Tuple<T, TState>>>.FromConverter(liftF);
    return Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Unfold<TState, T>(ff, init);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Unfold<T>(T source, Func<T, T> func)
{
    return Unfold<T>(source, func);
}
```

however writing your own version would be simpler:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Unfold<T>(T source, Func<T, T> func)
{
    T current = source;
    while(current != null)
    {
        yield return current;
        current = func(current);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does my question seem like a quality question to you, but not to so many others? I'm mystified. Anyways, thanks! This is exactly the definitive answer that I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You are referring to an `anamorphism` as mentioned here [linq-unfold-operator](https://surana.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/linq-unfold-operator/), which is the dual of a catamorphism.

`Unfold` is the dual of [`Aggregate`](https://surana.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/linq-unfold-operator/). `Aggregate` exists in the .Net Framework; `Unfold` does not (for some unknown reason). Hence your confusion.

```
/// seeds: the initial data to unfold
/// stop: if stop(seed) is True, don't go any further
/// map: transform the seed into the final data
/// next: generate the next seed value from the current seed 
public static IEnumerable<R> UnFold<T,R>(this IEnumerable<T> seeds, Predicate<T> stop, 
                                         Func<T,R> map, Func<T,IEnumerable<T>> next) {
    foreach (var seed in seeds) {
        if (!stop(seed)) {
            yield return map(seed);
            foreach (var val in next(seed).UnFold(stop, map, next))
                yield return val; 
        }
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
var parents = new[]{someType}.UnFold(t => t == null, t => t, 
                                     t => t.GetInterfaces().Concat(new[]{t.BaseType}))
                             .Distinct();
```

Comment: What has this got to do with your question? Your `Aggregate` function returns a collection. `Aggregate` is a fold, you appear to want an `Unfold`.

Comment: @Lee, it's just a placeholder so I can edit the answer if they close it and I do indeed find the correct .Net function. `Unfold` (in F#) needs a sequence to work on. In my case, I just have a single initial value and a function with which to get the next value. Understand?

Comment: Yes, so you could wrap the F# version if you want, but writing your own version would probably be easier.